# _CallbackResult was already set exception when consuming messages from RabbitMQ using pika

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika

I am using a RabbitMQ queue for my python tcp server implementation using pika. Client request to my server consumes messages related to that request from a common queue in no_ack fashion. Some times I get below exception when ran with more number of clients in parallel.

Stack trace for the exception is :

`result = channel.basic_get(queue=request_id, no_ack=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 1935, in basic_get
    self._basic_getempty_result.is_ready)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 1174, in _flush_output
    *waiters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 410, in _flush_output
    self._impl.ioloop.poll()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/select_connection.py", line 602, in poll
    self._process_fd_events(fd_event_map, write_only)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/select_connection.py", line 443, in _process_fd_events
    handler(fileno, events, write_only=write_only)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/base_connection.py", line 364, in _handle_events
    self._handle_read()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/base_connection.py", line 415, in _handle_read
    self._on_data_available(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/connection.py", line 1347, in _on_data_available
    self._process_frame(frame_value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/connection.py", line 1414, in _process_frame
    if self._process_callbacks(frame_value):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/connection.py", line 1384, in _process_callbacks
    frame_value)  # Args
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/callback.py", line 60, in wrapper
    return function(*tuple(args), **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/callback.py", line 92, in wrapper
    return function(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/callback.py", line 236, in process
    callback(*args, **keywords)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 102, in set_value_once
    self.signal_once()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 93, in signal_once
    assert not self._ready, '_CallbackResult was already set'`

Comment: I am not a Pika expert, but seems a threading problem. Do you use on channel for thread ? or you share the same channel between more threads ?

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Gabriele. I am sharing same connection between threads but not channel. Is that an issue ? I tried with separate connection for requests and issue gone. Is there a way to avoid burden of establishing connection for each request ?

Comment: The connection shared between more threads is a common practise. You shouldn't create a new connection each request. I don't know exactly what happens in pika [here](https://github.com/pika/pika/blob/master/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py#L94).
If you don't get a correct answer try to ask on https://github.com/pika/pika 
sorry.

Comment: @Gabriele : Thanks. added an issue in [pika](https://github.com/pika/pika/issues/707)